# How to merge the results of decomposed MySQL queries?

Tags: python, mysql

Maybe a stupid question...

For example, I have a `user` table and a `comment` table. And I need to serialize some comment (`id=1,2,3`) data like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "content": "blablabla",
        "time": "2018-12-01",
        "user": {
            "username": "Yriuns",
            "avatar": "https://.......",
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

So I first select several comment data:

```
SELECT `id`, `content`, `time`, `user_id` FROM `comment` WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3);
```

And the output `user_id` are, fox example, `[3, 2, 3]`.
So I query the `user` table:

```
SELECT `id`, `username`, `avatar` FROM `user` WHERE `id` IN (2,3);
```

My question is, how do I merge the `user` data to the `comment` list efficiently?

It seems that I need to construct a `map` for `user` and then traverse the `comment` list to build the final result. If so, it will be a nightmare when the level of nesting is deeper. For example, a `comment` may have a `target` it replies to, and the `target` may also have a `user` field.

**Note: Without Join**

Comment: Why not use a `JOIN`? It's the logical approach to this problem.

Comment: I know that, but `join` will be slow in some conditions. Sorry for typo.

Comment: You can use a subquery instead to achieve this.